# Solving a nonlinear PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I'd like to know the asymptotic ($ t\to\infty $) behavior of

$$
\partial_tu = -y\partial_{y}u + x^2 + y x \partial_xu - (1 + \partial_xu)^2
$$

with $ u(0, x, y) = 0 $.

`DSolve` doesn't give anything. What else could I try?

If I can't solve for $ u $ directly, can I at least get some approximation of $ \tilde{u}(x, y) $, assuming that $ u(t, x, y) = kt + \tilde{u}(x, y) $?

Comment: Nitpick:  $t \to \infty$ doesn't necessarily mean "stationary".  $\partial_t u \to 0$ is "stationary", but it's not a given that $u$ approaches this value from arbitrary initial conditions.

Comment: Also, would a numerical solution from `NDSolve` be acceptable?  If so, you'll probably need spatial boundary conditions;  what are they?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I agree stationary is the wrong word. Asymptotic would be better, I don't believe $\partial_tu\to 0$

Comment: @MichaelSeifert that's the problem. I don't know boundary conditions except for sub exponential growth at infinity. From my experience with the heat equation that should be enough, theoretically, but it might not be good enough for NDSolve

Comment: Even for the conventional heat equation, you still need to specify spatial boundary conditions.  What is the domain of $x$ and $y$ values you're interested in?  How does $u$ behave at the "edges" of this domain?  (Note that the domain in question may be "all of $\mathbb{R}^2$", though this is harder for `NDSolve` to handle without a few tricks.)  If you don't know the boundary conditions for a non-linear PDE, then I strongly suspect there's no hope of finding a solution.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The domain is $R^2$ indeed and I do think that subexponential growth identifies the solution I'm after uniquely. I do understand that that may not help numerically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96389/discussion-between-michael-seifert-and-bananach).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an analytic solution, but if "just some terms in an expansion" is fine, then the solution for small $t$ reads
$$
\begin{aligned}
u(t,x,y)&= \left(x^2-1\right)t+\\
&+x (x y-2)t^2\\
&+\frac{1}{3}  \left(x^2 (y (2 y-1)-4)-6 x y+4\right)t^3\\
&+\mathcal O(t^4)
\end{aligned}
$$

Check:

```
D[u[t, x, y], t] == -y D[u[t, x, y], y] + D[u[t, x, y], {y, 2}] + x^2 + y x D[u[t, x, y], x] - (1 + D[u[t, x, y], x])^2 /. u -> ((-1 + #2^2) #1 + #2 (-2 + #2 #3) #1^2 + 1/3 (4 - 6 #2 #3 + #2^2 (-4 + #3 (-1 + 2 #3))) #1^3 &)

Series[%, {t, 0, 2}] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Sorry, I suspect that $u(t,x,y)\sim kt +\tilde{u}(x,y)$ and I meant an expansion of $\tilde{u}(x,y)$. Updated the question

Comment: @Bananach An expansion in powers of *what*? what is the small parameter here?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe polynomials? Fourier modes? The result after a finite number of Newton iterations?

Comment: @Bananach I don't think you understood my question. You seem to be after some approximate solution; but approximate with respect to *what*? What is "small" here? What exactly do you mean by an "expansion of $\tilde u(x,y)$"? What exactly are you looking for? Unless you ask a precise question, you won't get a precise answer...

Comment: I did understand your question. I am looking for any formula that approximates $\tilde{u}(x,y)$. I gave the example of a Newton algorithm: after any finite number of iterations this might give an analytic expression and I'd be happy with such an expression. Alternatively, one could do a Picard iteration. I also gave the example of Fourier or polynomial expansions. The solution might be analytic and it might be possible to find the first few polynomial coefficients. I cannot say precisely what I want because I don't know what Mathematica can do. Obviously I would be most happy with the exact ..

Comment: .. solution but apparently Mathematica cannot do that. Hence, I'd be willing to accept the next best thing, whatever that may be.

Comment: @Bananach Sorry, but that doesn't make much sense: a solution of the form $u(t,x,y)=kt+\tilde u(x,y)$ does not exist. If you plug this into your PDE, you get a difference time-dependence on both sides, so the ansatz is inconsistent. If it works at all, it must do so under some approximation. If you don't tell me what the approximation is, the problem is ill-defined and unsolvable.

Comment: Huj,? I'd say you don't get any time dependence on both sides with the ansatz